# Make exponents line up with their base in terminal

Tags: output-formatting, command-line

For some reason, the exponents displayed on a terminal (Mac OS X 10.13) Mathematica 11.2 do not line up with their bases:

```
α^2*β^2*γ^3*ϵ^2*η^2*θ^7*κ^4*λ^2*μ^2*ν^2*ρ^2*τ^7*ϕ^5*φ^2*ψ^5*ω^9
```

[image]

For example, the 9 on the omega is very far away, and it makes it difficult to read the output.  What can I do line up the exponent with their bases?